# Laravel create and store failure

Tags: laravel, resources, store

I have a resource controller and create page. I need add some resources via store function. The store `post` url is `xxx/xxx`. Create `get` url is `xxx/xxx/create`. How can i `post` something via create url? Store `post` does have to be like `xxx/xxx/create`?

(Sorry for bad grammar)

Comment: you can see your routes by this command php artisan route:list

Comment: I did it but it's not my problem.